# Grouping to 2d array in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have simple videos views dataset:

```
df.head()
Out[10]: 
               video_id   views
datetime                       
2017-04-07  ---9wpGBsr4  1479.0
2017-04-08  ---9wpGBsr4  1883.0
2017-04-09  ---9wpGBsr4  2021.0
2017-04-10  ---9wpGBsr4  2083.0
2017-04-11  ---9wpGBsr4  2127.0
```

I am calculating weekly views per video:

```
resDf = df.groupby(['video_id', pd.TimeGrouper('W')]).sum()
```

So I have multi index video_id, date. Now I want to get a list of numpy arrays with views per every video or 2D numpy array effectively(dataset is large).

Now I am doing:

```
resDf2 = resDf.reset_index().set_index('datetime')
resultList = list(resDf2.groupby('video_id')['views'].apply(pd.DataFrame.as_matrix))
```

I think there is a better, faster way. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

What is your desired output in your example? Is this what you are after?

```
df.groupby(['video_id', pd.TimeGrouper('W')]).sum().values
Out[414]: 
array([[ 5383.],
       [ 4210.]])
```

Comment: a list of arrays with video weekly views. every row in that list  -  video views. every element in that array - views of that video for next week.